# blackmagic mini recorder camera and AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, camera, air

I have a panasonic hcx920 camera and found references online to people using the black magic mini recorder to use that cam as a webcam on their macs.  I even found references online to people testing it with FMLE / youtube's online recorder etc and it worked well.  So, from what I read, this is doable with flash.

However, when I hooked up the camera to the mini recorder... it works perfectly in their supplied "Media Express" application (so at least I know it's setup and hooked up correctly) but does not show as an available camera in my air application.  I tried tweaking all of the video format settings in the black magic setting in Mac preferences... with no success.

Anyone know the secret sauce for this recipe?  I feel like I must be missing something small somewhere.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think that you should use the "blackmagic mini recorder" as a video input source while your camera is hooked up to it.

Comment: I do? It goes from camera to mini recorder to thunderbolt port.  As I mentioned, the camera works fine as video input for other software... just doesn't show up as an available source in Camera.names

Comment: Is the "blackmagic mini recorder" is in `Camera.names` ?

Comment: no its not.  I found a reference where a guy piggybacks ffmpeg as a native process to grab capture card input... but I thought AIR supported them as a camera input... it's looks like... NOT.